# Meteor is showing extra results after refresh, even DB has single row

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am creating a sample Meteor app, but whenever I refresh the browser the value gets added. In the image if you see even the console output is 1, but the results displayed in the browser is getting added by number of values in the database.[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOSeI.png)

HTML code

```
<template name="leaderboard">
{{#each playero}}
    {{name}}: {{score}}
{{/each}}
<br />
<h7>No. of players:</h7> {{playercount}}
</template>
```

JS code

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players2');
if(PlayersList.find({name: "David"}).count()<=0) {
    PlayersList.insert({ name: "David", score: 0 });
console.log("No. of records in the colection:"+PlayersList.find({name:        
"David"}).count());
}
if(Meteor.isClient)
{
 Template.leaderboard.helpers({
'playero': function(){
    return PlayersList.find().fetch();
},
'playercount': function(){
    return PlayersList.find().count();
}
});    
}
```

Comment: why is it getting incremented 18 times and not say 25 times? Is the count 18 repeatable every time that you start the app? 

In general, there is some code smell. The seeding code should be part of fixtures.js in the server. Also, check for count === 0 for seeding. There is no need to find "David" for seeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your insert code inside a server clause, like this:

```
if(Meteor.isServer)
{
    if(PlayersList.find({name: "David"}).count()<=0) {
        PlayersList.insert({ name: "David", score: 0 });
        console.log("No. of records in the colection:" + PlayersList.find({name:        
"David"}).count());
    }
}
```

As configured in your example above, the code will run on both the server and client. While running on the client, the data has not yet been published to the client resulting in 0 Players while the code is executing. It will then go inside the if-statement and insert a new player, therefore printing a count of 1. It is actually 18, but the data is not on the client yet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I'll be looking for here is subscriptions. At the time of a fresh page load, the server collection is not yet synced to the  browser and the collection is thus empty.

If you want to "count" a collection in the browser, remember to wait until all subscriptions has been initiated and loaded.

See also: Autorun, Subscription and Template.subscriptionsReady (to ensure that templates wait until subscriptions are ready).

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tonight.